# How do I properly get a table within a table in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm trying to create a payroll register detail report.  There are a number of sections to the report, but basically there is an employee info section(name, id, masked SSN, etc) an earnings section(pay type, hours, rate, and dollars, a tax section(itemized list of taxes--fed, state, local, etc), a deductions section(an itemized list of deductions--health, dental, etc), a benefits section(health, 401k, etc).  Here is an image of the report drawn up as a model:

[image: Payroll Register Detail]

For my stored procedure, i created the following temp table:

```
CREATE TABLE #EmployeePayDetail(
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[EmployeeID] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
[EmployeeName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[EmployeeSSN] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[CheckNumber] [int] NULL,
[Description] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
[Units] [decimal](19,5) NULL,
[Rate] [decimal](19,5) NULL,
[Amount] [decimal](19,5) NULL,
[Section] [int] NULL,
[Sort] [int] NULL   )
```

Most are obvious, however, the section field is used to determine which section I was going to put the data in.

```
1=Earnings
2=Taxes
3=Deductions
4=Benefits
```

The name, SSN, and employeeID would be denormalized and First(x) would be used in the EmployeeInfo section.

So my thought was to put a List Region on the Body and then put four tables one for each section on the List.  Each list would then Filter on section.  When I tried this I received the error:

The tablix '' has a detail member with inner members.  Detail members can only contain static inner members.

So next I tried to put the tables within the cells of another table.  Supposedly you can nest tables.  When I tried this, I received the same error.  So I asked google and the suggestion I got was to try to put these in the header section of the table rather than the detail.  When I tried that, I got all of the data run together.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Not sure what your issue is. For your situation, I would have a main table that groups by **Employee** then add 3 extra detail rows and put each of your 4 tables in the detail rows. 

A pic of your report's **Detail** view might help figure out your issue.

Comment: You could have it all in one table with a column group on Section?

Answer (score 2):

OK, here is what I was able to do to make it work.

I created a table to hold the structure of the report.  It had a column for each of the Earnings, Taxes, Deductions, Benefits, and Totals section.  Then I added a parent group to group by Employee and it added another column to the left of Earnings which I labeled Employee Info.

Here's the important part: ***I deleted the detail row and copy/pasted my data tables inside the header row.***  Then to get the totals, I added a row below inside group and did the normal sum columns stuff.

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 1):

Your list idea strikes me as the best. The error you received occurs when the List has no grouping, but contains tables. If you group the list itself on EmployeeID I think that you should get the desired results.